# Testing concurrency in Java

Tags: java, multithreading, testing, concurrency, blocking

According to book *Java Concurrency in Practice* at Listing 12.3 we could test a concurrent code using the following sample code:

```
void testTakeBlocksWhenEmpty() {
 final BoundedBuffer<Integer> bb = new BoundedBuffer<Integer>(10);
 Thread taker = new Thread() {
  public void run() {
   try {
    int unused = bb.take();
    fail(); // if we get here, it’s an error
   } catch (InterruptedException success) { }
  }
 };
 try {
  taker.start();
  Thread.sleep(LOCKUP_DETECT_TIMEOUT);
  taker.interrupt();
  taker.join(LOCKUP_DETECT_TIMEOUT);
  assertFalse(taker.isAlive());
 } catch (Exception unexpected) {
  fail();
 }
}
```

Let's say that the following steps are executed:

1. `taker` thread started.
2. `bb.take()` returned successfully and we are just a little bit before the `fail()` method run.
3. It is called the `interrupt()` method.
4. We are at the `catch` block of the `taker` thread.

So, we are at the catch block at the moment but actually the test method failed. It is failed and we are never informed.

Is this right? If yes how could we fix this?

Comment: Never saw BoundedBuffer data structure before in Java. What does take() function do? Please provide some references.

Comment: The `Thread.sleep` will make chances close to certainty that if `take`does not block, the `fail` method will be called before the thread is interrupted. And anyway: interruption is just setting a flag. You'll have to block in order for the exception to be thrown.

Comment: @Fildor:Let's say that `LOCKUP_DETECT_TIMEOUT` time is not enough. Should I increase this time? Is this a right edit or should I change something at the code?

Comment: @Aniket Thakur: The BoundedBuffer does not exist in Java. It as a custom class using Semaphore to create a blocking operation. It reminds me the BlockingQueue. The only reference I can provide is "Chapter 12. Testing Concurrent Programs - Listing 12.3"

Comment: Did you actually run into this problem or is this more like an academical question? If take() does not block and its runtime is smaller than the sleeptime , let's say sleeptime is at least double the peek take()-on-no-block-time then you are safe enough. By the way, when the thread on which take is executed has passed take() and then the interrupt is called, what will happen? Nothing. The exception will not be thrown, except the thread will enter a method in fail() that will throw one.

Comment: It is an academical question. Just to understand better if this is a possible problem. In the real life I would increase the time but I was wondering, whether I could provide another way to test.

Comment: You should cleanup your question: “but actually the test method failed”—what does that really mean, “failed” in which way? “It is failed and we are never informed.”— again, what do you mean with this? Who ought to inform who in which way?

Answer (score 1):

`take` is supposed to block on an empty queue. So the expected sequence of events is:

- `taker.start();` => start the thread
- `Thread.sleep(LOCKUP_DETECT_TIMEOUT);` wait to make sure the thread is started and `take` has been called. The actual value of the constant is hard to estimate, but anything above a few hundreds of millis should be enough - alternatively you could use a CountDownLatch to know when the taker thread is started
- in taker thread: `bb.take();` => is supposed to block - if it doesn't `fail()` is called and the test fails
- in main thread: `taker.interrupt();` => the `take()` method is supposed to exit with `InterruptedException`
- in main thread: `taker.join();` => wait for some time to allow the taker thread to finish
- in main thread: `assertFalse(taker.isAlive());` => confirm that the taker thread has exited and is not blocked in the `take` method any more

Version with a latch (it assumes that if the thread is interrupted *before* `take` is called, `take` will exit with an InterruptedException - if not then you have no other way but to add some random sleep before calling `started.await()`):

```
void testTakeBlocksWhenEmpty() {
 final CountDownLatch started = new CountDownLatch(1);
 final CountDownLatch ended = new CountDownLatch(1);
 final BoundedBuffer<Integer> bb = new BoundedBuffer<Integer>(10);
 Thread taker = new Thread() {
  public void run() {
   try {
    started.countDown();
    int unused = bb.take();
    fail(); // if we get here, it’s an error
   } catch (InterruptedException success) { }
   ended.countDown();
  }
 };
 try {
  taker.start();
  started.await();
  taker.interrupt();
  assertTrue(ended.await());
 } catch (Exception unexpected) {
  fail();
 }
}
```

You should add a timeout to your test method or to the latch (long enough to not interfere if the test passes, for example 5 seconds). That will avoid blocking your whole test suite.